# C++ write a number on two bytes

Tags: c++

I am new to the low level c++, and I find it a bit hard to understand how to manipulate bits. I am trying to do the following to use in a compression algorithm I am trying to make:

```
unsigned int num = ...;//we want to store this number
unsigned int num_size = 3;//this is the maximum size of the number in bits, and
//can be anything from 1 bit to 32

unsigned int pos = 7;//the starting pos on the 1st bit.
//this can be anything from 1 to 8

char a;
char b;
```

if the `num_size` is 3 and pos is 7 for example, we must store `num`, on the **7th** and **8th** bit of `a` and on the **1st** bit of `b`.

Comment: Learn about bit operations like masking (bitwise and) and shifting. Or possibly `union`.

Comment: can you please help me solve this particular problem?

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to work with num_size > 15

Comment: In that case we will use more than 2 chars

Comment: in 2 bytes we can hold 16 bits, not 15. what to explain better? if pos = 1, means start writing from 1st bit of this char.

Comment: This case doesn't really work like that (as you should know by now). Instead you present your problem (the original problem you try to solve) and how you tried to solve it together with any errors or other problems with that solution. We give hints on how to either fix your solution, or present hints to other possible solutions. And you learn from the hints about how to solve this yourself. At least that's the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: The original problem is to modify huffman's algorithm. Now, none will write this for me, so I decided to do it myself. While I can understand the theory, I don't know how to manipulate bits, as I never done this before.

Comment: Also I am not confident to "play" with bits, because it might seem like it works but nasty errors can appear.

Comment: I don't know why you are working on this project, Luka, but what you are saying in your posts/comments - and looking at the here makes it sound like you aren't interested in learning/understanding, you just want someone to provide you with code. "I'm afraid to try" is definitely an early indicator that you might not be suited to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just?

```
a = num << (pos-1);
b = ((num << (pos-1)) & 0xFF00) >> 8;
```

To read num back just

```
num = ((unsigned int)a + ((unsigned int b) << 8)) >> (pos - 1);
```

Note, this doesn't do any sanity checks, such as whether all the relevant bits fit in a and b, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to read this number from those 2 bits?

Comment: Also your code doesn't work correctly in case the num = 5 and pos = 7

Comment: `b = (num << (pos-1)) & 0xFF) >> 8;` how are the ')' and '(' going here?

Comment: Luka, there were a couple of typos. Hopefully it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific test case, the highest number that fits into 2 `unsigned char` is actually `65535`.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned char high(int input)
{
    return (input >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

unsigned char low(int input)
{
    return input & 0xFF;
}

int value(unsigned char low, unsigned char high)
{
    return low | (high << 8);
}

int main()
{
    int num = 65535;
    unsigned char l = low(num);
    unsigned char h = high(num);

    int val = value(l, h);
    std::cout<<"l: "<<l<<" h: "<<h<<"  val: "<<val;
}
```